# JQuery Ajax not passing variables to PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I want to pass some variables about a specific chat in order to pull all the chat messages from the database using JQuery and Ajax. I have a list with hidden inputs for each conversation/chat like so:

```html
<ul class="userlist">
    <li class="thisuser">
        <div class="thisuserimg"><img src="images/userpics/user1.png" alt=""/></div>
        <div class="thischatdets">
            <p class="thischatuser"><span>This is my username buddy</span><span>Mar 09</span></p>
            <b class="thischatad"><span>Closed</span>This is my ad title buddy</b>
            <p class="thischatmsg">This is the last msg in the chat buddy</p>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="abtitem" value="has-itemid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtbuyer" value="has-userid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtseller" value="has-userid" />
    </li>
    <li class="thisuser">
        <div class="thisuserimg"><img src="images/userpics/user1.png" alt=""/></div>
        <div class="thischatdets">
            <p class="thischatuser"><span>This is my username buddy</span><span>Mar 09</span></p>
            <b class="thischatad"><span>Closed</span>This is my ad title buddy</b>
            <p class="thischatmsg">This is the last msg in the chat buddy</p>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="abtitem" value="has-itemid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtbuyer" value="has-userid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtseller" value="has-userid" />
    </li>
    <li class="thisuser">
        <div class="thisuserimg"><img src="images/userpics/user1.png" alt=""/></div>
        <div class="thischatdets">
            <p class="thischatuser"><span>This is my username buddy</span><span>Mar 09</span></p>
            <b class="thischatad"><span>Closed</span>This is my ad title buddy</b>
            <p class="thischatmsg">This is the last msg in the chat buddy</p>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="abtitem" value="has-itemid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtbuyer" value="has-userid" />
        <input type="text" class="abtseller" value="has-userid" />
    </li>
<ul>
```

I have a couple of ajax requests on this page like so:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Send Message
        $("#newmsg").submit(function(e){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "server/server.php",
                data: $("#newmsg").serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        
        //Autoreferesh Userlist
        setInterval(function() { // this will execute the function every 1s
            let url = "server/test.php";
            $.get(url, function(d) { // jquery function that 'does' the GET request
                $('.userlist').html(d) // when we have a returned request, populate the element above with the body of the returned request ( plain text )
            });
        }, 3000);
        
        //Load chat messages
        $("ul.userlist").on("click","li", function(){
            //alert("Chat content loaded successfully!");
            //alert($(this).find(".thischatuser span").text());
            var abtitem=$(this).find(".abtitem").val();
            var abtbuyer=$(this).find(".abtbuyer").val();
            var abtseller=$(this).find(".abtseller").val();
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url:"server/test.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{abtitem:abtitem, abtbuyer:abtbuyer, abtseller:abtseller},
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    let url = "server/test.php";
                    $.get(url, function(data) { // jquery function that 'does' the GET request
                        $('.chatarea').html(data) // when we have a returned request, populate the element above with the body of the returned request ( plain text )
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Now, the "Load chat messages" code is responsible for the post and display of the data I need, and it seems to be working because I'm receiving a response from the server. However, the server response shows that the post variables are not sent.
Note: Have tried nearly all the available answers on SO but none of them works!

Comment: Can you add the relevant form `#newmsg`?

Comment: `the server response shows that the post variables are not sent`...why what does the server do with them? You can check the raw data which is _sent_ by using your browser's Network tool, you don't need to rely on the server processing the data and responding.

Comment: From this, we can see (by looking at the payload in the network tool for the test.php request) that the data is definitely sent in the Ajax POST: https://jsfiddle.net/uLs72vpe/ So I'd guess maybe whatever issue is occurring is actually somewhere in the server-side PHP code. It's hard to be sure, since we cannot see any of the PHP code.

Comment: Either that, or your issue comes from some sort of misunderstanding. In the "success" of your POST function, you're making _another_ request to test.php, but a GET this time. Why are you doing that? You've literally just sent a request to test.php, so what is the purpose of sending another one immediately? And this time of course, you are not sending any parameters with it. So if they're needed for what you want to do, it isn't going to work. Why not just make the POST request directly return the data you're interested in seeing? That would be a lot more efficient.

Comment: @ADyson did a var_dump($_POST) on the server and it returns empty

Comment: From which request? As I said, you are making two separate consecutive requests to the same script, which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense